# Calculate standard deviation for intervals in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, standard-deviation

I would like to calculate standard deviations for non rolling intervals.

I have a df like this:

```
value std year
  3   nan 2001
  2   nan 2001
  4   nan 2001
 19   nan 2002
 23   nan 2002
 34   nan 2002
```

and so on. I would just like to calculate the standard deviation for every year and save it in every cell in the respective row in "std". I have the same amount of data for every year, thus the length of the intervals never changes.

I already tried:

```
df["std"] = df.groupby("year").std()
```

but since the right gives a new dataframe that calculates the std for every column gouped by year this obviously does not work.

Thank you all very much for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

try via `transform()` method:

```
df['std']=df.groupby("year")['value'].transform('std')
```

OR

If you want to find the standard deviation of multiple columns then:

```
df[['std1','std2']]=df.groupby("year")[['column1','column2']].transform('std')
```